# @Inject does not seem to work in my @WebServlet, the dependency is null

Tags: servlets, cdi

This is my servlet code. I'm using java ee and servlet to save my information. I used dependency injection. when I press button to run the servlet I have the error:

`Cannot invoke "appuser.model.RegisterBean.setFirstName(String)" because "this.registerBean" is null`

```
package appuser.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import appuser.model.RegisterBean;
import appuser.model.RegisterDao;

@WebServlet("/register")
public class RegisterController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Inject
    private RegisterDao registerDao;
    @Inject
    private RegisterBean registerBean;   
    
    public RegisterController() {
        super();
      }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getParameter("btnRegister") != null) {
        String firstname = request.getParameter("txtFirstname");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("txtLastname");

        registerBean.setFirstName(firstname);
        registerBean.setLastName(lastname);

        String registerValidate = registerDao.authorizeRegister(registerBean);
    .
    .
    .

    }
    }
}
```

registerBean code:

This code added after edit.

```
package appuser.model;

public class RegisterBean {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public RegisterBean(String firstName,
                        String lastName,
                        String email,
                        String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
```

I am newbie in Java and I really appreciate your help to solve this problem.

Comment: First thing is to tell which server make/version exactly you're using, and how exactly the `RegisterBean` class is annotated (including package names), and where exactly you placed the `beans.xml` file and what exactly its file contents are. Then we can move forward.

Comment: I added RegisterBean class, and don't know what is beans.xml. I'm using java 11.

Comment: Thus, your `RegisterBean` doesn't have any CDI bean defining annotation. The beans.xml is mentioned in every decent CDI tutorial/book. "Java 11" isn't a server make/version.

Answer (score 0):

CDI will never leave a field annotated `@Inject` as null, if it can't inject something it will throw an exception.

This means that if you do see `null` in a field annotated `@Inject` you can be confident that for one reason or another CDI has not processed that class.

Here is my checklist for when I see this error:

- Was the objected  directly calling `new`? If so CDI will not process it.
- Is there a beans.xml file in the archive, and if so is there anything there that will prevent this class being processed. The earliest versions of CDI require a beans.xml file before they will process an archive.
- Is there a Bean Defining Annotation in the archive (e.g. `@RequestScoped`). Without a beans.xml file modern versions of CDI will not process an archive unless at least one class has a bean defining annotation. Note that `@Inject` is *not* a bean defining annotation.
- Is the NPE coming from the constructor? CDI does field injection after the constructor finishes so sometimes you get an NPE if someone tried to use an injected field in the constructor.